# Spring/SPeL: condition specific Cache control from one class to another

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

tl;dr;

### I am looking for a way to set a "condition" attribute on a Spring Cacheable annotation from another class.  Is there such a way?

Using Spring Cache where it should cache ONLY whenever a certain method has been invoked.  This method is in ClassA, the method (data) to cache is in ClassB.  What I want to do is something like this:

```
public ClassA implements myInterface {
...  
    private Boolean inProcess = false;

    public void cacheWhenThisMethodCalled() {
        try {
            inProcess = true;
            // do work here, somewhere along the line
            // the method in ClassB gets called
        } finally {
            inProcess = false;
        }
 }
```

ClassB:

```
public ClassB {
...
    @Cacheable(cacheNames={"aCache"}, condition="#classA.inProcess")
    public ValueClass findValueClass(UUID id)
```

However, I can't find the right condition for the SPeL to work.  I have tried many combinations, none successfully.  ClassA is a SpringBean, but the @Bean annotation returns the Interface, not the class.  Can this be made to work?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `ThreadLocal` - you would need to do that anyway for thread safety - otherwise a different thread can change the field.

This works fine...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class So47580936Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47580936Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Bar bar) {
        return args -> {
            bar.cacheFromHere();
            bar.dontCacheFromHere();
        };
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "foos", condition = "T(com.example.So47580936Application$Bar).cacheit()")
        public String foo() {
            System.out.println("here");
            return "foo";
        }

    }

    @Component
    public static class Bar {

        private static final ThreadLocal<Boolean> cacheit = new ThreadLocal<>();

        @Autowired
        private Foo foo;

        public static boolean cacheit() {
            return cacheit.get() == null ? false : cacheit.get();
        }

        public void cacheFromHere() {
            try {
                this.cacheit.set(true);
                System.out.println("Cache:" + this.foo.foo());
                System.out.println("Cache:" + this.foo.foo());
            }
            finally {
                this.cacheit.remove();
            }
        }

        public void dontCacheFromHere() {
            System.out.println("Don't:" + this.foo.foo());
            System.out.println("Don't:" + this.foo.foo());
        }

    }

}
```

result:

```
here
Cache:foo
Cache:foo
here
Don't:foo
here
Don't:foo
```

**EDIT**

Or, you can just make the `ThreadLocal` a `@Bean` ...

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class So47580936Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So47580936Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(Bar bar) {
        return args -> {
            bar.cacheFromHere();
            bar.dontCacheFromHere();
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadLocal<Boolean> cacheit() {
        return new ThreadLocal<>();
    }

    @Component
    public static class Foo {

        @Cacheable(cacheNames = "foos", condition = "@cacheit.get() ?: false")
        public String foo() {
            System.out.println("here");
            return "foo";
        }

    }

    @Component
    public static class Bar {

        @Autowired
        private ThreadLocal<Boolean> cacheit;

        @Autowired
        private Foo foo;

        public void cacheFromHere() {
            try {
                this.cacheit.set(true);
                System.out.println("Cache:" + this.foo.foo());
                System.out.println("Cache:" + this.foo.foo());
            }
            finally {
                this.cacheit.remove();
            }
        }

        public void dontCacheFromHere() {
            System.out.println("Don't:" + this.foo.foo());
            System.out.println("Don't:" + this.foo.foo());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Upvoted as this is close, maybe very close!  In my actual code, your Foo and Bar (my ClassA and ClassB) don't know anything about one another.  Your 'Bar' needs a 'Foo' autowired.  My ClassA only calls a high level Service, that in turn calls various lower level services, eventually several of these end up making the same call to "Bar" (which hits the DB), so Caching it seems highly desirable.   What do you think about creating a "CacheControl" class shared by both (and that contains the ThreadLocal?